# How many people were sanctioned in Spain for criticizing the police, under Spain's 2015 "citizens security law"?

Tags: freedom-of-speech, spain, police

There have been some [2015] Spanish [media reports](https://www.thelocal.es/20150817/woman-fined-800-for-photographing-police-car) that after the adoption of the 2015 Citizens Security Law (Ley Orgánica 4/2015), which among other things

> forbids "the unauthorized use of images of police officers that might jeopardize their or their family's safety or that of protected facilities or police operations"

some people have been fined, e.g. for posting photos of illegally parked police cars or

> calling local police “slackers” on Facebook.

*Time* [reported](https://time.com/3944245/spain-security-law-ley-mordaza-dictatorship-censorship-gag/) (also in 2015) that:

> Under the law, citizens can be fined the equivalent of almost $700 for insulting an officer, over $33,000 for recording and disseminating images of police officers, and more than $664,000 for participating in an unauthorized protest outside government buildings, the New York Times reports.

Five year later, have any statistics been compiled (e.g. by human rights groups) how often they think the Spanish law was used to "gag" criticism of the police?